# MochaJS + Global variables + Redux

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, redux

I've been looking for an answer but couldn't find one.

This is my test.js:

```html
process.env.__ENVIRONMENT__ = 'production'; // This does not work
global.__ENVIRONMENT__ = 'production'; // This does not work, either


import assert from 'assert';
import Product from '../../../../app/modules/products/containers/Product';

console.log(Product);

describe('Array', function() {

  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present (suplicate)', function() {
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
    });
  });
});
```

This is my containers/Product.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as ProductActions from '../actions/products';

// @connect(state => { user: state.user })
class Product extends Component {
  // Normal code
}
```

The problem comes with the actions, this is my /actions/products.js file:

```html
import {root_url, request_config} from '../../../config'; // This line here is my problem

export const PRODUCT_INVALID = 'PRODUCT_INVALID';
export const PRODUCT_FETCHING = 'PRODUCT_FETCHING';
export const PRODUCT_FETCHED = 'PRODUCT_FETCHED';
export const PRODUCT_FETCH_FAILED = 'PRODUCT_FETCH_FAILED';

function fetchProduct(slug) {

  return (dispatch) => {

    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCHING, slug: slug });

    return fetch(`${root_url}/p/${slug}`, request_config)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(
        (result) => dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCHED, slug: slug, result }),
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCH_FAILED, slug: slug, error });
        }
      );
  }
}

function shouldFetchProduct(state, slug) {
  console.log("state", state);
  const product = state.products[slug];

  if (!product ||
    product.readyState === PRODUCT_FETCH_FAILED ||
    product.readyState === PRODUCT_INVALID ) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

export function fetchProductIfNeeded(slug) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchProduct(getState(), slug)) {
      return dispatch(fetchProduct(slug));
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I make an import to /config/index.js, this is the content of the file:

```html
if (__ENVIRONMENT__ === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./production')
} else {
  module.exports = require('./default')
}
```

And there is basically where mocha fails, as '____ENVIRONMENT____' is not defined.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV` is what you should be using.

Comment: That's what i'm using, but I transalate it to __ENVIRONMENT__ in my server.js

global.__ENVIRONMENT__ = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'default';

Comment: So why are you referring to it as `__ENVIRONMENT__` instead of `global.__ENVIRONMENT__`?

Comment: ...nevermind, forgot that you could do that with `global`.  I suppose it's worth a try just using `process.env.NODE_ENV` everywhere?  That's what I've always done and it works just fine

Comment: Using windows, I changed this line in package.json to ->

"test": "SET global.__ENVIRONMENT__ = 'production' && node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"

Comment: It still fails because of __ENVIRONMENT__ not defined

Comment: Mmm good point, I changed the /config/index.js so that it uses process.env.NODE_ENV instead of __ENVIRONMENT__ and it works now.

Comment: Cool!  Although I'm still confused as to why your previous implementation wasn't working.  Glad to hear you're all set now :)